# Faster alternatives to lsof

Tags: tcp, lsof

I want to extract the process id of a certain process in order to shut it down. The process is a local web server using a certain port (localhost:3000), and I am currently doing it like this to extract the relevant line:

```
lsof|grep localhost:3000
```

but the `lsof` command is too slow. Is there a faster way to extract the process id?

Comment: `lsof -i` list just the network connections.

Comment: @HananN. I tried it, but it is still very slow. Using netstat as suggested in the answers is much faster.

Comment: `lsof` is not the slow part, using all the name resolutions and ip resolving is.  Make it all numeric and it will go fast.

Comment: @Marcin Your information was actually helpful as much as the answers given. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can`t use `killall` `pgrep` or `pkill`?

Comment: @Nils Yes. I can't narrow down what I want to terminate just by the process name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try netstat, I cannot say whether its faster or slower, however.

```
netstat -tanp | awk '$4 ~ /:8443$/ {sub(/\/.*/, "", $7); print $7}' | sort -u
```

Comment: I understand to use -p option, Linux requires you to be root user.

Comment: It's definitely faster since netstat only lists network connections (and not all the open files)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and accurate response. I helped me a lot.

Answer (score 12):

You can put a -n option to lsof and then it remove the DNS resolution, which can accelerate the display

Comment: Yes, that seems to sove the problem, and is helpful. It was partly suggested by Marcin in a comment to my answer.

Comment: time reported lsof taking 10 seconds regardless of the n option.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ss -p -l '( sport = :3000 )'|awk -F"," 'NR!=1{print $2}'
```

This will print the PID of the process listening on 3000

`time` reports that this completed in 0m0.018s.